# How to set background-position in ngStyle angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Happy Friday!

I've quite confuse on how to set `background-position-x` in `[ngStyle]` angular 4 - ionic 3. What is the right way to implement `background-position-x`? My expected output will be:

`background-position-x:5% !important`

---

Here's my current codes:

In controller:

```
    this.currentIndex = this.slides.getActiveIndex();
    this.background_position_x = (this.currentIndex+1)*5+"% !important";
    console.log("background position -x:"+this.background_position_x);
```

Console log output:

[image]

---

In html view:

```
<div class="container" 
    [ngStyle]="{
        'background':'url('+lesson_details.background_picture+'),linear-gradient(to top, rgb(160, 160, 160) -20%, rgb(1, 1, 1) 149%)',
        'background-position-x': background_position_x}">
```

Comment: I believe you are doing it fine. What's the problem?

Comment: The background position did not effect @NabinPaudyal

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<div class="container" 
    [ngStyle]="{
         'background':'url({{lesson_details.background_picture}}),linear-gradient(to top, rgb(160, 160, 160) -20%, rgb(1, 1, 1) 149%)',
         'background-position-x': '{{background_position_x}}"></div>
```